# How to catch errors in a route's decorator and respond with a JSON response

Tags: python, api, flask, error-handling, flask-restful

In our app there's an authentication decorator that checks for user's integrity among other things, we want to handle errors that might occur in the decorator such as invalid user credentials and reply with a json response for that route, what's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to change the return value of the handler inside a decorator:

```py
def auth(handler):
    def _wrapped_handler(request):
        if not authorised(request):
            return jsonify({"status": "forbidden"}), 403
        return handler(request)
    return _wrapped_handler

@route("/foo/bar")
@auth
def handler(request):
    return jsonify({"status": "ok"}), 200
```

I don't know what conventions you are following, so its possible that e.g. the `_wrapped_handler` should accept other arguments, but this is the gist of it.

It helps to remember that

```py
@decorator
def function():
    ...
```

is short-hand for

```py
def function():
    ...

function = decorator(function)
```

In terms of best practice, a common pattern is to define a general exception handler which converts exceptions into HTTP Responses. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/errorhandling/#generic-exception-handlers

If you went down this route, you would raise an appropriate exception in the decorator rather than return a 403 response directly.